# operator OR on char port to java

Tags: java, c++

Hello could any one explain to me this line of code written in c++?

```
couleur[i][c]=couleur[i][c] ||
couleur[noeud][c];
```

Arrays are char type.
What does this or do? ( arrays indexes are meaningless so i don't explain them),
because i need to rewrite this line to Java code and in Java i got error 
"bad operand types for binary ||".
I checked this code in c++ and can get what it does - doesn't matter what value chars get it always assign ' '.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a || b
```

Is for booleans. Both in Java and C++. However, in C++, if `a` and/or `b` are not booleans, the compiler will cast them to a boolean first. Anything non-zero becomes true. In Java, this would be:

```
(a != 0 || b != 0) ? 1 : 0
```

So, to translate your piece of code, use this:

```
couleur[i][c] = (couleur[i][c] != 0 || couleur[noeud][c] != 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

Your `' '` you are getting is probably a null byte (0, or `'\0'`).

Comment: what about the result in java? You can't assign a boolean to a char

Comment: I missed something. Check my update. I guess that your `' '` is in fact 0. (Sometimes represented by `'\0'`)

Comment: my compiler hinted me to cast result to char

Comment: @user1291518 if `couleur` is used as a string (`char*`) the `\0`'s would mark the end of that string in C while they are legal characters in Java. You might need to take care of that manually. The cast to `char` is required because literal numbers (i.e. `0 : 1`) are considered `int` in Java and that's 32bit while `char` is just 16 > potential loss of precision = you have to cast.

Answer (score 0):

In `C language` you can use OR operator on any value, it will be casted to boolean from compiler with rule that any non-zero value is true.
You have to rewrite has:

```
couleur[i][c]=(couleur[i][c] != 0) || (couleur[noeud][c] != 0);
```

but you are in trouble because `couler[][]` is typed as char and Java result is a `boolean`, so use ternary operator as:

```
couleur[i][c]=(couleur[i][c] != 0) || (couleur[noeud][c] != 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: I was 4 mintues faster. Plus, your code doesn't compile. Can't assign boolean to char, will be the compiler error.

Comment: OK. You faster. Good for you. I was correcting code (like mine code, yours doesn't compile at first try) because I see my error while posting